# Interactive MapIcon, Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, maps, pushpin, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

so, I have an app which allows users to add recommendations for restaurants and places in a certain area,  when added a MapIcon is added to map and data pulled from parse, what i need is a way that when the MapIcon is clicked that is displays the information for that recommendation, another option is adding a custom user control to the map. put I would prefer the first way. Any Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You say "so, I have an app", so what's not working? and where your code?

Comment: essentially i need some way to add a click event to a mapicon or add the user control to the xaml map,

Comment: Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapIcons" >
                <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:MapIconExpanded x:Name="MapIconE" Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}" Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,0.5"/> 
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl>
aparently it is already the child of another element

Comment: i cant post too much code due to confidentiality and the company's regulations.

Comment: Please add your code and ask question specific to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make MapIcon (and other children of the MapElements collection) interactive. These are controlled by the native MapControl.

What you can do, is add normal XAML elements to the MapControls Children collection e.g. via a MapItemsControl. There you can use whatever you like. Buttons, Images with tapped handlers and so on. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620947.aspx

Comment: You talk about MapIcon but link to an example with Pushpins, those are two completely different things.

Comment: You didn't read my comment completely. I said that he *CAN NOT* use MapIcon, *BUT* that there is an *ALTERNATIVE*, which are MapItems to which I posted a link.
So please remove the downvote.

Comment: Sorry, can you edit your answer, otherwise I cant remove the downvote.

Comment: Its alright back then i created a custom control to do what i wanted it to do :)